# Google Cloud LocalDatastoreHelper failing to connect

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

`LocalDatastoreHelper` from the Google Cloud API started failing one Jenkins worker VM; not on other Jenkins worker VMs nor various development machines. [This known issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/2309) looks very similar but has a slightly different stacktrace.

(I am using Google Cloud SDK 202.0.0 with cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.0)

```
 com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Deadline exceeded  Deadline exceeded
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out  connect timed out
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:183)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.commit(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:153)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:485)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:482)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commit(DatastoreImpl.java:481)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commitMutation(DatastoreImpl.java:475)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:435)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreHelper.put(DatastoreHelper.java:54)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:410)
```

Comment: I'm with GCP support. File a new case for this so we can have a look on the VM and the configuration, please. This kind of error is usually related to network.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.  Actually I think it is not related to network , since the "Test helper" is completely internal to unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in  Google's Cloud library. I opened [this ticket](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2309), and eventually  it was resolved. So this problem probably is obsolete.